# Configure local php endpoint for Axios in Nuxt JS

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

I want to use Axios to make client AJAX calls that point to a local PHP file. Why PHP? I have tons of security-tested approaches in a simple PHP-based API that work great and don't need re-inventing.

I'm guessing I'm missing something easy, but so far I've had a wonky/hacky approach that works. Right now, I've got a PHP file in the `/static` folder, and in `nuxt.config.js` I have a proxy setup:

```
... other config stuff 
axios: {
    proxy: true
},
proxy: {
    '/api': 'http://some-site.local/api.php'
}
... other config stuff
```

In order for the url above to resolve, I have a host entry setup via MAMP that resolves `http://some-site.local` to the `/static` directory in my Nuxt project.

So far, it works. But, it requires setting up MAMP to have the `hosts` entry, and when it comes to `npm run build`, this approach fails, because the build will take the PHP files from the `/static` and put them the the docroot of `/dist`, but that breaks the API proxy setup for Axios in `nuxt.config.js`.

I really don't want to install some PHP package (I've seen that Laravel has one that works with Nuxt), because the aim is just to be able to have a couple PHP files within my Nuxt project instead of a full library. Anyone have any insight on what I'm missing to make this work better?

Answer (score 2):

## For NUXT and PHP all in one project (small project)

Lets say there is already Node and PHP-CLI installed.

Create NUXT project:

```
npx create-nuxt-app my-app
```

Create file `static/api/index.php` (lets say):

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
$rawPaylaod = file_get_contents('php://input');

try {
  $payload = json_decode($rawPaylaod, true);
} catch (Exception $e) {
  die(json_encode(['error' => 'Payload problem.']));
}

echo json_encode([
  'echo' => $payload,
]);
```

Install dependencies

```
npm i -D concurrently
npm i @nuxtjs/axios @nuxtjs/proxy
```

Update `config.nuxt.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  ...

  modules: [
    ...
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/proxy',
  ],

  ...

  proxy: {
    '/api': {
      target: 'http://localhost:8000',
      pathRewrite: {
        '^/api' : '/'
      }
    },
  },

  axios: {
    baseURL: '/',
  },
}
```

Update `package.json`:

```
"dev": "concurrently -k \"cross-env NODE_ENV=development nodemon server/index.js --watch server\" \"php -S 0.0.0.0:8000 static/api/index.php\"",
```

And it's ready.

Now locally in development API will be available thanks to proxy and after deployment just under path.

Comment: Thanks for posting this. I went through and installed dependencies (including `cross-env`, which I needed), but when I attempt to start I get errors: "Error: No build files found in /Users/xxxxxxxx/Sites/..../server/index.js/.nuxt/dist/server. Use either `nuxt build` or `builder.build()` or start nuxt in development mode." I changed the dev command to `"dev": "concurrently -k \"nuxt --\" \"php -S 0.0.0.0:8000 static/api/index.php\""` but it's still not working. PHP is indeed firing but the app doesn't load correctly. Is it something in the `dev` command in package.json?